# Just installed Ubuntu but booting error displayed "Insert system disk in drive."

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bios, toshiba

Until a few days ago I was mainly a Windows user, since I couldn't install linux via dual boot on my computer. I tried everything several times, did everything right, but the problem was that after I installed any linux distro, once I rebooted my pc it would go straight to Windows.

I got tired of this, people who understood a lot about the matter also tried for a few hours and told me my BIOS was uncapable of dual boot.

So, the other day I decided to erase Windows and go on with Ubuntu only.

So, after installed, and with no Windows to boot to, my pc just doesn't boot to any OS, unless it's with a usb stick, and displays the message *"Insert system disk in drive. Press any key when ready..."*.

My laptop model is a Toshiba Portege R930.

I tried a lot of things, among them using the boot-repair-disk. Excused to say it also didn't work, but [the report it gave me is in the link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15030520/), if it may help.

Thanks in advance for any help, I'm really desperate.

MLobo

Comment: From live installer run this and see if you can boot the new "Windows" entry. ` sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"` Toshiba is now like HP & Sony and uses description as part of UEFI boot. That is specifically not allowed in UEFI spec. And since only booting Ubuntu you can just use the description "Windows" for Ubuntu/grub's shim boot file. It does not seem to check actual files (yet).http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: @oldfred first of all, thanks for you help. I reinstalled ubuntu once more and ran the command you gave me, but it still won't boot. The output of the command was the following: https://gist.github.com/MLobo1997/a02812fd18cdf41c14f2

Comment: @oldfred since my last comment, I've tried the method A you sent me in the link, problem is, I later realized it was meant to dual-boot problems only. So, I reinstalled Ubuntu once more and immediately created a BootInfo with boot-repair, which is in the link below. I've tried to fix this problem for days now and have been without computer ever since, so if you could give me a hand and try to give me a tutorial of how I should proceed, I couln't be more thankful. http://paste.ubuntu.com/15046665/

Comment: Latest does not show 0008 and 0009 as the Windows duplicate name. But since you still have the Microsoft folder in the ESP - efi system partition, UEFI may auto add a new UEFI entry for Windows on  reboot. I would backup entire ESP, its not large. And delete the /EFI/Microsoft folder.  Then using efi bootmgr remove any Windows entries and re-run command above to add a "Windows" entry using shim to boot. Only if you have to delete an UEFI entry: Delete entry change XXXX to correct entries. Some UEFI require all 4 HEX char, other just need 1 or 2 significant char.
`sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B`

Comment: You have a variant on the same problem described in [this question.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/733076/boot-repair-not-working-on-hp-elitebook-2170) See my answer to it.